# Add extension (OCI8) to PHP - Linux

Tags: php, database, oracle, php-extension, oci8

After much pain, I managed to build oci8, installing all the libraries from oracle and many other missing libraries.

Now I have a `oci8.so` file under `usr/lib/php5/20131226` and the line `extension=oci8.so` in the `php.ini` file.

However when I launch `phpinfo()` I can't see it, and when I try to use a `oci_` function I get nothing, no error, no result.

If anyone knows why, or how to make this work, I'll be really grateful. Thanks

Comment: check the error logs to see if/why it's not being loaded. just because it built successfully doesn't mean it's actually USABLE.

Comment: Assuming the database on a different server, have you installed the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) as described in the [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php)?

Comment: Yes i did, I fannly worked it out, I installed every Oracle instant client instance (basic + sdk + sqlplus) and built oci8 manually, and built php5 manually, and added `extension` to php.ini inside `php5/cli` and `apache2` configuration file

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create oci8.ini file with row:

extension=oci8.so

2. Activate extension for php.

How to install Oracle Instant client and oci8 for Linux Debian 8/9/10: https://skalolaskovy.ru/comp-various/535-debian-and-oracle (in Russian)

Comment: At first you need to check all php versions on your server and choose that you use.